# Multiple array in for loop with powershell

Tags: powershell

Hey guys，I want run the for loop like below

$a is gt 0 and lt 5,$b is gt 2 and lt 7,I nned loop result like this（this is $a and $b ）

this is 1 and 3
this is 2 and 4
this is 3 and 5
this is 4 and 6

Hope someone can help me，thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop and assign `$a + 2` to `$b`:

```
for ($a = 1; $a -lt 5; $a++)
{ 
    $b = $a +2;

    Write-Host "this is $a and $b"
}
```

Output:

```
this is 1 and 3
this is 2 and 4
this is 3 and 5
this is 4 and 6
```

Comment: Thanks Jessen，but I notice that "$a" can not put in "[]",I want to simplify my script like below

$array=(Get-Content D:\new.txt -TotalCount -1)[-1]
$data=$array.split(" ")
$d8=$data[8]
$d9=$data[9]
$d10=$data[10]
$d11=$data[11]
$d12=$data[12]
$d13=$data[13]

if($d8 -eq "CPULd")
{
"SVR360`t$d8`t$d9" |out-file "D:\result.txt"  -append -Encoding ASCII
"SVR360`t$d10`t$d11" |out-file "D:\result.txt"  -append -Encoding ASCII
"SVR360`t$d12`t$d13" |out-file "D:\result.txt"  -append -Encoding ASCII
}

How to simplify and make it looks clean？

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [jisaak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35390047/712649) (which is spot on), you can also use multi value assignment to initialize both `$a` and `$b` in the same `for` loop:

```
for($a,$b = 1,3;$a -lt 5 -and $b -lt 7;$a++,$b++)
{
    Write-Host "this is $a and $b"
}
```

Comment: ah nice one, didnt know that.